# Creating a Sticky Header and Sidebar with a Scrollable Content Area using Flexbox in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper containing three div boxes, and I've applied display: flex to the wrapper. I want Div Box A and B to be sticky while only Div Container C should have a scrollbar. I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve this using the provided code.
I want the div boxes to be next to each other that's why I also use "display: flex"

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  background: green;
}

.a {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: bisque;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.b {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.c {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c">
  </div>
</div>
```

See Code Example but it didnt work